# bootstrap modal is not working in fullCalendar plugin

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4, fullcalendar

I was try to create the event calendar. I have to create the modal for adding event in to the calendar is not showing bootstrap modal.but when i using js prompt box i can add the event.but i need to add more information using bootstrap modal.

```html
<?php
    //index.php
    include('header.php');
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"> </script>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:30px">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">Holiday List</div>
                <div class="col-md-3" align="right">
                    <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Back To Home</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div id="calendar">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="formModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog model-center">
        <form id="add_event">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Make New holiday</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select name="event_action" id="event_action" class="form-control">
                            <option value="1">Holiday</option>
                            <option value="2">Absant Day As Present</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="event_name" id="event_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Event Name" />
                        <span id="error_event_name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" name="create_report" id="add_event" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Create Report</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable:true,
        header:{
            left:'prev,next today',
            center:'title',
            right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        events: 'timetable/load.php',
        selectable:true,
        selectHelper:true,
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            //$('#formModal').modal('show');//this not show the bootstrap model
            var title = prompt("Enter Holiday Event Title");
            var type = prompt("Enter Holiday type");
            if (title && type) {
                var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                $.ajax({
                    url:"timetable/insert.php",
                    type:"POST",
                    data:{title:title,type:type, start:start, end:end},
                    success:function () {
                        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                        alert("Added Successfully");
                    }
                })
            }
        },
        editable:true,
        eventResize:function(event) {
            var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
            var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
            var title = event.title;
            var id = event.id;
            $.ajax({
                url:"timetable/update.php",
                type:"POST",
                data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id},
                success:function() {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                    alert('Event Update');
                }
            })
        },

        eventDrop:function(event) {
            var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
            var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
            var title = event.title;
            var id = event.id;
            $.ajax({
                url:"timetable/update.php",
                type:"POST",
                data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id},
                success:function() {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                    alert("Event Updated");
                }
            });
        },

        eventClick:function(event) {
            if ( confirm("Are you sure you want to remove it?") ) {
                var id = event.id;
                $.ajax({
                    url:"timetable/delete.php",
                    type:"POST",
                    data:{id:id},
                    success:function() {
                        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                    alert("Event Removed");
                    }
                })
            }
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

`title = prompt("Enter Holiday Event Title");` prompt box and type text box working perfectly.but is not good way to add event.that why i think about go to the bootstrap modal. so how do i fixed this error?

Comment: You don't appear to have included any bootstrap CSS or JavaScript files into your page. P.s. you didn't actually tell us what error you're getting...do you see any messages in the Console, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include **Bootstrap** JS into your code, cause modals work with JS:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/